# Ruby on Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian WEBrick crash probably during asset compilation?

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Installed this app that runs fine on my Mac called WAGN.

Tried compiling Ruby from scratch and installed 2.0.0, 2.1.5 then 1.9.3 using RBENV.

Tried using the packages from Raspbian which use an older 1.9.3-p194 and they all end up with the same crash. NOTE: the folder ruby1.9.1 below contains 1.9.3, it's just that the name of the package remained the same and it got an upgrade.

Any ideas on how to deal with this? (Quick recap, the Pi 2 is a quad core 900mhz ARM7 with 1GB ram)

```
wagn server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-03-24 21:14:45] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-24 21:14:45] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [arm-linux-eabihf]
[2015-03-24 21:14:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22094 port=3000
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [arm-linux-eabihf]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0166 p:---- s:0775 b:0775 l:000774 d:000774 CFUNC  :Call
c:0165 p:0036 s:0770 b:0770 l:000774 d:000769 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13
c:0164 p:0005 s:0768 b:0768 l:0024b4 d:000767 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:84
c:0163 p:---- s:0764 b:0764 l:000763 d:000763 FINISH
c:0162 p:---- s:0762 b:0762 l:000761 d:000761 CFUNC  :call
c:0161 p:---- s:0760 b:0760 l:000759 d:000759 CFUNC  :TryCatch
c:0160 p:0019 s:0757 b:0757 l:0024b4 d:0024b4 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:83
c:0159 p:0045 s:0754 b:0753 l:000774 d:000ab4 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13
c:0158 p:0033 s:0751 b:0751 l:000750 d:000750 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:206
c:0157 p:0013 s:0747 b:0747 l:000774 d:000774 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:11
c:0156 p:0027 s:0742 b:0742 l:000808 d:000741 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:19
c:0155 p:0028 s:0740 b:0740 l:0023c0 d:000739 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:248
c:0154 p:---- s:0738 b:0738 l:000737 d:000737 FINISH
c:0153 p:---- s:0736 b:0736 l:000735 d:000735 CFUNC  :call
c:0152 p:---- s:0734 b:0734 l:000733 d:000733 CFUNC  :HandleScope
c:0151 p:0017 s:0731 b:0731 l:0023c0 d:001c8c BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:245
c:0150 p:---- s:0729 b:0729 l:000728 d:000728 FINISH
c:0149 p:---- s:0727 b:0727 l:000726 d:000726 CFUNC  :call
c:0148 p:---- s:0725 b:0725 l:000724 d:000724 CFUNC  :Locker
c:0147 p:0053 s:0722 b:0722 l:0023c0 d:0023c0 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:244
c:0146 p:0026 s:0718 b:0718 l:000717 d:000717 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:204
c:0145 p:0013 s:0714 b:0714 l:000808 d:000808 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:18
c:0144 p:0026 s:0710 b:0709 l:002434 d:000708 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45
c:0143 p:0007 s:0706 b:0706 l:001294 d:000705 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75
c:0142 p:---- s:0703 b:0703 l:000702 d:000702 FINISH
c:0141 p:---- s:0701 b:0701 l:000700 d:000700 CFUNC  :call
c:0140 p:---- s:0699 b:0699 l:000698 d:000698 CFUNC  :Locker
c:0139 p:0027 s:0696 b:0696 l:001294 d:001294 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73
c:0138 p:0011 s:0691 b:0691 l:002434 d:002434 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43
c:0137 p:0125 s:0686 b:0686 l:000685 d:000685 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:76
c:0136 p:0022 s:0680 b:0680 l:000679 d:000679 METHOD /home/pi/test/tmp/set/type/1002-coffee_script.rb:14
c:0135 p:0031 s:0675 b:0674 l:001ef4 d:000673 LAMBDA /home/pi/test/tmp/set/type/1002-coffee_script.rb:20
c:0134 p:---- s:0672 b:0672 l:000671 d:000671 FINISH
c:0133 p:0056 s:0670 b:0669 l:000660 d:000668 BLOCK
```

TOO LONG TO INCLUDE, PLEASE ASK FOR INFORMATION IF NEEDED

```
2.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in `block in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:18:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:204:in `enter'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:244:in `lock_scope_and_enter'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:244:in `Locker'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:244:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:245:in `block in lock_scope_and_enter'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:245:in `HandleScope'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:245:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in lock_scope_and_enter'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:19:in `block in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:11:in `methodcall'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:206:in `enter'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13:in `block in methodcall'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:83:in `try'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:83:in `TryCatch'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:83:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:84:in `block in try'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in methodcall'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/function.rb:13:in `Call'

    -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

    -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
```

TOO LONG TO INCLUDE, PLEASE ASK FOR INFORMATION IF NEEDED

```
* Process memory map:

    00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 53332      /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    00010000-00011000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 53332      /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    00011000-00012000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 53332      /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    00400000-03425000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    24200000-24219000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    27c00000-27d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2a800000-2a809000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2a809000-2a80a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2a80a000-2a8ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    2a8ff000-2a900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2b200000-2b300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2b700000-2b709000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2b709000-2b70a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2b70a000-2b70c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    2b70c000-2b74c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2c000000-2c100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    2e600000-2e700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    30500000-30600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    30f00000-31000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    32f00000-33000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    33ac6000-33ec6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    34a00000-34a19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    36200000-36300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    37000000-37100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    39c51000-39d51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3b900000-3b909000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3b909000-3b90a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3b90a000-3b9ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    3b9ff000-3ba00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3be00000-3bf00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3f100000-3f109000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3f109000-3f10a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3f10a000-3f16a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    3f16a000-3f16b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    43974000-43980000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    43980000-43990000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    43990000-439a4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    45200000-45300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    46a00000-46a49000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    47600000-47700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    4a200000-4a300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    4f000000-4fc00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    4fc00000-50000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    58f00000-59000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5a300000-5a339000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5b100000-5b109000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5b109000-5b10a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5b10a000-5b10f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    5b10f000-5b14c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5db00000-5dc00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5de00000-5df00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5f100000-5f109000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5f109000-5f10a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5f10a000-5f1ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    5f1ff000-5f200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74900000-74909000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74909000-7490a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7490a000-749ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    749ff000-74a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74b00000-74c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74d00000-74e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74f00000-74f31000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    74f31000-75000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    75100000-75200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    752a8000-752a9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    752a9000-753a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:22145]
    753a9000-753ab000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 68635      /lib/libnss_mdns4.so.2
    753ab000-753b2000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 68635      /lib/libnss_mdns4.so.2
    753b2000-753b3000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 68635      /lib/libnss_mdns4.so.2
    753b3000-753b7000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4255       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_dns-2.13.so
    753b7000-753be000 ---p 00004000 b3:02 4255       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_dns-2.13.so
    753be000-753bf000 r--p 00003000 b3:02 4255       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_dns-2.13.so
    753bf000-753c0000 rw-p 00004000 b3:02 4255       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_dns-2.13.so
    753c0000-753c2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 68636      /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
    753c2000-753c9000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 68636      /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
    753c9000-753ca000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 68636      /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
    753ca000-753cb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    753cb000-7544a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7544a000-75453000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4263       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
    75453000-7545a000 ---p 00009000 b3:02 4263       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
    7545a000-7545b000 r--p 00008000 b3:02 4263       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
    7545b000-7545c000 rw-p 00009000 b3:02 4263       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
    7545c000-7546d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4257       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
    7546d000-75474000 ---p 00011000 b3:02 4257       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
    75474000-75475000 r--p 00010000 b3:02 4257       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
    75475000-75476000 rw-p 00011000 b3:02 4257       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
    75476000-75478000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    75478000-7547e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4259       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
    7547e000-75485000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 4259       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
    75485000-75486000 r--p 00005000 b3:02 4259       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
    75486000-75487000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 4259       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
    75488000-75489000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    75489000-75498000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:22157]
    75498000-754a2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4245       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
    754a2000-754a9000 ---p 0000a000 b3:02 4245       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
    754a9000-754aa000 r--p 00009000 b3:02 4245       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
    754aa000-754ab000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:02 4245       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
    754ab000-7556a000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 16117      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    7556a000-75571000 ---p 000bf000 b3:02 16117      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    75571000-75575000 r--p 000be000 b3:02 16117      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    75575000-75577000 rw-p 000c2000 b3:02 16117      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    75577000-7557d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7557d000-759bc000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529565     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/init.so
    759bc000-759c4000 ---p 0043f000 b3:02 529565     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/init.so
    759c4000-759e3000 rw-p 0043f000 b3:02 529565     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/init.so
    759e3000-759e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

TOO LONG TO INCLUDE PLEASE ASK FOR INFORMATION IF NEEDED

```
    76620000-76621000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529172     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32le.so
    76621000-76628000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529172     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32le.so
    76628000-76629000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529172     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32le.so
    76629000-7662a000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529172     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32le.so
    7662a000-7662b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529171     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32be.so
    7662b000-76632000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529171     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32be.so
    76632000-76633000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529171     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32be.so
    76633000-76634000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529171     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_32be.so
    76634000-76635000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529170     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16le.so
    76635000-7663c000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529170     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16le.so
    7663c000-7663d000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529170     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16le.so
    7663d000-7663e000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529170     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16le.so
    7663e000-7663f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529169     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16be.so
    7663f000-76646000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529169     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16be.so
    76646000-76647000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529169     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16be.so
    76647000-76648000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529169     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/utf_16be.so
    76648000-7664d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 395321     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.so
    7664d000-76654000 ---p 00005000 b3:02 395321     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.so
    76654000-76655000 rw-p 00004000 b3:02 395321     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.so
    76655000-76657000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529176     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/md5.so
    76657000-7665e000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 529176     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/md5.so
    7665e000-7665f000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 529176     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/md5.so
    7665f000-76660000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 529176     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/md5.so
    76660000-7666a000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529224     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/zlib.so
    7666a000-76671000 ---p 0000a000 b3:02 529224     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/zlib.so
    76671000-76672000 r--p 00009000 b3:02 529224     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/zlib.so
    76672000-76673000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:02 529224     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/zlib.so
    76673000-76692000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529219     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/socket.so
    76692000-76699000 ---p 0001f000 b3:02 529219     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/socket.so
    76699000-7669a000 r--p 0001e000 b3:02 529219     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/socket.so
    7669a000-7669b000 rw-p 0001f000 b3:02 529219     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/socket.so
    7669b000-766a9000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529196     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so
    766a9000-766b0000 ---p 0000e000 b3:02 529196     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so
    766b0000-766b1000 r--p 0000d000 b3:02 529196     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so
    766b1000-766b2000 rw-p 0000e000 b3:02 529196     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so
    766b2000-766d9000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529200     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/date_core.so
    766d9000-766e1000 ---p 00027000 b3:02 529200     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/date_core.so
    766e1000-766e2000 r--p 00027000 b3:02 529200     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/date_core.so
    766e2000-766e3000 rw-p 00028000 b3:02 529200     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/date_core.so
    766e3000-766fc000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 53223      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
    766fc000-76703000 ---p 00019000 b3:02 53223      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
    76703000-76704000 r--p 00018000 b3:02 53223      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
    76704000-76705000 rw-p 00019000 b3:02 53223      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
    7670c000-7670d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529151     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    7670d000-76714000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529151     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    76714000-76715000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529151     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    76715000-76716000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529151     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    76716000-7671b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529214     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/psych.so
    7671b000-76722000 ---p 00005000 b3:02 529214     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/psych.so
    76722000-76723000 r--p 00004000 b3:02 529214     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/psych.so
    76723000-76724000 rw-p 00005000 b3:02 529214     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/psych.so
    76724000-76725000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529205     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/fcntl.so
    76725000-7672c000 ---p 00001000 b3:02 529205     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/fcntl.so
    7672c000-7672d000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 529205     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/fcntl.so
    7672d000-7672e000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 529205     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/fcntl.so
    7672e000-76742000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 5186       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.7
    76742000-7674a000 ---p 00014000 b3:02 5186       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.7
    7674a000-7674b000 r--p 00014000 b3:02 5186       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.7
    7674b000-7674c000 rw-p 00015000 b3:02 5186       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.7
    7674c000-7688f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 10829      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    7688f000-76897000 ---p 00143000 b3:02 10829      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    76897000-768a4000 r--p 00143000 b3:02 10829      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    768a4000-768ac000 rw-p 00150000 b3:02 10829      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    768ac000-768b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    768b0000-768f4000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 10828      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0
    768f4000-768fb000 ---p 00044000 b3:02 10828      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0
    768fb000-768fd000 r--p 00043000 b3:02 10828      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0
    768fd000-76901000 rw-p 00045000 b3:02 10828      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0
    76904000-76909000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529220     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/stringio.so
    76909000-76910000 ---p 00005000 b3:02 529220     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/stringio.so
    76910000-76911000 r--p 00004000 b3:02 529220     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/stringio.so
    76911000-76912000 rw-p 00005000 b3:02 529220     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/stringio.so
    76912000-76953000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529212     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/openssl.so
    76953000-7695a000 ---p 00041000 b3:02 529212     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/openssl.so
    7695a000-7695b000 r--p 00040000 b3:02 529212     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/openssl.so
    7695b000-7695d000 rw-p 00041000 b3:02 529212     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/openssl.so
    7695d000-76961000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529221     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/strscan.so
    76961000-76968000 ---p 00004000 b3:02 529221     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/strscan.so
    76968000-76969000 r--p 00003000 b3:02 529221     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/strscan.so
    76969000-7696a000 rw-p 00004000 b3:02 529221     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/strscan.so
    7696a000-7696c000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529202     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest.so
    7696c000-76974000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 529202     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest.so
    76974000-76975000 r--p 00002000 b3:02 529202     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest.so
    76975000-76976000 rw-p 00003000 b3:02 529202     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest.so
    76976000-76979000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529178     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/sha1.so
    76979000-76980000 ---p 00003000 b3:02 529178     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/sha1.so
    76980000-76981000 r--p 00002000 b3:02 529178     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/sha1.so
    76981000-76982000 rw-p 00003000 b3:02 529178     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/digest/sha1.so
    76982000-76984000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529204     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/etc.so
    76984000-7698b000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 529204     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/etc.so
    7698b000-7698c000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 529204     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/etc.so
    7698c000-7698d000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 529204     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/etc.so
    7698d000-76992000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529213     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/pathname.so
    76992000-76999000 ---p 00005000 b3:02 529213     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/pathname.so
    76999000-7699a000 r--p 00004000 b3:02 529213     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/pathname.so
    7699a000-7699b000 rw-p 00005000 b3:02 529213     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/pathname.so
    7699b000-7699d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529122     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    7699d000-769a4000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 529122     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    769a4000-769a5000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 529122     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    769a5000-769a6000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 529122     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/trans/transdb.so
    769a6000-76a27000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76a27000-76b9e000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 16545      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
    76b9e000-76bbe000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 16120      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
    76bbe000-76bc5000 ---p 00020000 b3:02 16120      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
    76bc5000-76bc6000 rw-p 0001f000 b3:02 16120      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
    76bc6000-76cea000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4254       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
    76cea000-76cf1000 ---p 00124000 b3:02 4254       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
    76cf1000-76cf3000 r--p 00123000 b3:02 4254       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
    76cf3000-76cf4000 rw-p 00125000 b3:02 4254       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
    76cf4000-76cf7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76cf7000-76d5f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4262       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
    76d5f000-76d66000 ---p 00068000 b3:02 4262       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
    76d66000-76d67000 r--p 00067000 b3:02 4262       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
    76d67000-76d68000 rw-p 00068000 b3:02 4262       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
    76d68000-76d6f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4253       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt-2.13.so
    76d6f000-76d76000 ---p 00007000 b3:02 4253       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt-2.13.so
    76d76000-76d77000 r--p 00006000 b3:02 4253       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt-2.13.so
    76d77000-76d78000 rw-p 00007000 b3:02 4253       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt-2.13.so
    76d78000-76d9f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76d9f000-76da1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4260       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
    76da1000-76da8000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 4260       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
    76da8000-76da9000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 4260       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
    76da9000-76daa000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 4260       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
    76daa000-76db0000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4241       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
    76db0000-76db7000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 4241       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
    76db7000-76db8000 r--p 00005000 b3:02 4241       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
    76db8000-76db9000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 4241       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
    76db9000-76dcd000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4247       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
    76dcd000-76dd4000 ---p 00014000 b3:02 4247       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
    76dd4000-76dd5000 r--p 00013000 b3:02 4247       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
    76dd5000-76dd6000 rw-p 00014000 b3:02 4247       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
    76dd6000-76dd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76dd8000-76f81000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 19084      /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
    76f81000-76f88000 ---p 001a9000 b3:02 19084      /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
    76f88000-76f8d000 rw-p 001a8000 b3:02 19084      /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
    76f8d000-76f9c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76f9e000-76fa0000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 529141     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    76fa0000-76fa7000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 529141     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    76fa7000-76fa8000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 529141     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    76fa8000-76fa9000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 529141     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux-eabihf/enc/encdb.so
    76fa9000-76faa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76faa000-76fad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:22096]
    76fad000-76faf000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 27297      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
    76faf000-76fb6000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 27297      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
    76fb6000-76fb7000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 27297      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
    76fb7000-76fd4000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 4248       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
    76fd6000-76fdc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    76fdc000-76fdd000 r--p 0001d000 b3:02 4248       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
    76fdd000-76fde000 rw-p 0001e000 b3:02 4248       /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
    7ed80000-7eda1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
    7ee3d000-7ee3e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
    ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]


    [NOTE]
    You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
    Bug reports are welcome.
    For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

    Aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8809).  The solution is to remove therubyracer gem from your `Gemfile`. Then install nodejs on your Pi, which you can do with the following command:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Oh good it works! "sudo gem uninstall therubyracer" then edit the Germfile and add a # before the line that says "gem 'therubyracer'" and restart you Pi.